# HTTP Error 503. "The service is unavailable."

Tags: 2013, web-application, iis

One of my Web Applications shows error:

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

I checked in IIS Application pool and started the respective services but the error still persist

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The Issue is fixed now,

The Error is because of the **service account credentials**

*Thanks pals for your inputs*

Answer (score -1):

Please check if there are some errors in the Event Viewer. It might give you a clue. In my situation I had to low memory. And the logs in Event Viewer told me about it.

Comment: Can you please extend this answer with more detail, to make it more useful? :)